# How do I get rid of a Google custom search snippet hover border?

Tags: css, google-custom-search

I'm trying to restyle a google custom search page and having...mixed results. The thing that's bothering me the most is the hover border. From where does it come and how can I get rid of it?

Picture below. See? that 1px black line.

[image: picture of the border]

Edit: I meant to include the following, somehow didn't:

Here's a link to the public url for a [similar google search engine](https://cse.google.com/cse/publicurl?cx=012400264131474929546:1k4wuwgvcku). The lines are in full effect there. Just enter a search term.

The element that appears to have the hoverborder also has a mess of inline javascript.

```
<td onclick="if (this.className == 'gsc-table-cell-snippet-close gsc-collapsable') { this.className = 'gsc-table-cell-snippet-open gsc-collapsable'; } else if (this.className == 'gsc-table-cell-snippet-open gsc-collapsable') { this.className = 'gsc-table-cell-snippet-close gsc-collapsable'; };" class="gsc-table-cell-snippet-close">
```

So, anyone?

P.S. Plan B here is go with a different google search theme (they don't all have the hoverborder) but we already have the current theme looking just the way we want and customizing google search isn't fun, so we'd really prefer to stick with what we have.

Comment: Screen shot doesn't help, have a URL? If you can't share then use your browser's dev tools to determine what you need to override.

Comment: Absolutely right. I wrote the question in a separate markdown editor, somehow failed at copy-paste. Added relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That URL was what I needed. You should be able to override their style with the following:

```
.gsc-webResult.gsc-result:hover {
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: On my application, this solution _mostly_ works, but it does introduce a 1px 'jiggle' when I hover over a snippet. Still, `border-left: 1px solid white;` does fine and what I really needed was the class name, and that's it up there. Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: Great, glad it worked. That was my intention (to point you in the right direction) since I didn't know what styling you needed. Edited my answer with your desired styling.